# CS50 IDE clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: c, ubuntu, clang, cs50

I am learning C programming from CS50. I was trying to to build parity program. Here is my code,

```
# include <cs50.h>
# include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int n=get_int("n: ");
    if(n%2==0)
    printf("even\n");
    else
    printf("odd\n");
}
```

when I try to compile I get the following error,

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
```

Can anyone tell what's going on here?

I was  trying to compile this on official CS50 IDE and I got that error .

This is my first question on stackoverflow, so pardon me if I am doing any bad formatting  or styling.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: That error message is only the summary. The relevant messages are shown before that line. I would assume the linker complains about missing `get_int`. Do you link `cs50` library? How do you build your project?

Comment: @Gerhardh  I do not know much about it I'm a beginner . I have no prior programming experience. I am doing this on CS50 online IDE which is an ubuntu system .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 2):

I figured it myself. There was a folder with same name as my c source file. That's why clang got confused.